# Examples of Struts2 applications

Tags: security, jsp, struts2, code-analysis, static-analysis

I am working on a static analysis for detecting security vulnerabilities in web applications, and I am looking for some web applications to run my analysis on.

More specifically I am right now looking for open-source web applications that use the Struts2 framework, but I have a hard time finding such applications.

Does anyone know of some more or less complete and open-source web applications written using Struts2 (or possibly just plain JSP)?

Comment: [This one](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/01/tutorial-struts2-hibernate-example-eclipse.html) is an open source struts2 app with basic CRUD features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very complete and stable Struts2 application i use for log file analysis is [KonaKart](http://www.konakart.com/). The advantage is that you can set it up on your server, including demo data and configure it and use it as you wish.

In terms of openness:

"Only the customizable parts of KonaKart are open source. These include the Struts action classes and
forms, the JSPs, the payment modules, order total modules, shipping modules and the GWT One Page
Checkout code. They are shipped under the GNU Lesser General Public License."

If you need 100% open source it is not for you.

Comment: Thank you for that. I will look into KonaKart. The parts that are open-source are exactly those I need

Comment: I am sure you will like it. Documentation is great and the forum is active. And who knows, you may sell an e-shop to somebody while you check for security vulnerabilities... :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Projects Using WebWork or Struts2**
https://cwiki.apache.org/S2WIKI/projects-using-webwork-or-struts2.html

**Others**

- http://api.cnn.com/
- http://www.allhomes.com.au/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I however need the code in order to be able to analyze it, and I don't think any of these pages provide that.

Answer (score 0):

Check these tutorials. there downloads are available. [link1](http://www.vaannila.com), [link2](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/tutorials.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I am interested in "real" application rather than "Hello World" style tutorial examples.